# Check column if values differ between rows and insert number alternately

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel-Table**

```
     |      A       |       B
-----|--------------|-----------------
1    |  Product_A   |   
2    |  Product_A   |
3    |  Product_A   |
4    |  Product_B   |       1
5    |  Product_C   |       2
6    |  Product_C   |
7    |  Product_D   |       1
8    |  Product_E   |       2
9    |  Product_E   |
10   |  Product_E   |       
11   |  Product_F   |       1
12   |              |
```

In the above Excel table I have a list of different products in `Column A`. 
A product can appear **multiple times**.

Currently, I am using this `VBA` to check if a product in `Column A` switches between the **current** and the **previous** row. 
If the products switch the number `1` is inserted in `Column B`.

```
Sub FilB()
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & N).Formula = "=IF(A2=A1,"""",1)"
End Sub
```

However, now I want to include the condition that if the **previous** inserted number was `1` the **next** number should be `2` and if the **previous** inserted number was `2` the **next** number should be `1`.

How do I have to modify the `VBA` to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Alternating Values

**Excel**

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",MOD(COUNT(B$1:B1),2)+1)
```

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilB()
    Dim n As Long
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2:B" & n).Formula = "=IF(A2=A1,"""",MOD(COUNT(B$1:B1),2)+1)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with formula. Copy the below formula in **B2** and then all the way down

> =IF($A2<>$A1,IF(ISNUMBER($B1), $B1+1, 1), "")

**EDIT 1**

As per comments, below is updated formula

> =IF($A2<>$A1,IF(OR($B1=2, $B1 = ""), 1, 2), "")

Comment: Will that alternate between 1 and 2?

Comment: I think you got your answer but just to explain, it first checks if the values in column **A** are different, if so, it then check if the row above in column **B** has a number. If it does, it will add one to that number and place it in current row column **B**. If it doesn't, it will put 1 in current row column **B**

Comment: Zac - OP wants it to alternate between 1 and 2, not keep adding 1 and I can't see that your formula does that?

Comment: If you put `A, B, C, D` in range `A2:A5`, then your formulas in range `B2:B5` will return `1, 2, 3, 4` instead of `1, 2, 1, 2`.

Comment: @SJR and VBasic2008: absolutely correct. I miss read OP's requirements. I'll remove the answer as OP has already accepted an answer

Comment: Why delete? - Even a not completed answer may be helpful for other readers showing a different approach and possibly guiding them to a proper solution :-) @Zac